# Eclipse key for "jump to first/next error"?

Tags: c, eclipse

There are quite some keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse, so it is hard to search.

I want after an unsuccessful build in my Eclipse CDT, to press a single button and the following to happen:

- The build console should scroll up to the **first error** or warning in the build
- The appropriate file should be opened at the appropriate line (just like clicking on the error)

When I press the same key again, I want the same to happen for the next item.

This is so basic, that I am sure it is already done. How do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

- Next error: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
- Previous error: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: My Eclipse Indigo doesn't seem to support those. As a matter of fact, now I discovered the search field over the keyboard bindings and the only results for `error` are `Show in (Error Log)` and `Show View (Error Log)`.